# can't access member attribute on dynamically created component

Tags: angular

here is my code

template:

```
<button (click)='openModal()'>open</button>
```

.ts

```
@Component({
  ...,
  entryComponents: [ModalComponent]
})

...

  constructor(
    ...
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private viewContainerRef:ViewContainerRef
  ) { }


  openModal(){
    this.cmpRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(
      this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ModalComponent)
    );
    this.cmpRef.instance.close.subscribe(e => console.log(e));
  }
```

I get:

```
Property 'close' does not exist on type 'Component'.)
```

but when I do `console.log(this.cmpRef.instance);` I can see my component with all members (including close)

close is an EventEmitter en ModalComponent:

```
@Output() close: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Comment: Please add the code that shows the `close` function.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your error message is a static error, not a runtime error.

```
(this.cmpRef.instance as ModalComponent).close.subscribe(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: is it possible to put "as ModalComponent" into a variable?

Comment: @BenjaminMcFerren I don't think so, but I'm not a TS specialist. You can put it in a function and assign this function to a variable.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer could you please share a syntax example on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You should cast your instance to `ModelComponent` for the TypeScript compiler to pick it up:

```
(<ModalComponent>this.cmpRef.instance).close.subscribe(e => console.log(e));
```